# In php looping, how to make radiobuttons for one result independant from the next

Tags: php

I am making a quiz and the questions are coming from my database. Each choice (A, B, C) has its own radiobutton and this is my code to display the quiz:

```
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultx)) {
    echo '<tr><td>Question '.$qcounter.'<br/></td></tr>';
    $qcounter++;
    //output rows for radiobuttons
    echo "<tr><td>".($row['Question'])."</td></tr>";
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="A" id="question-1-answers-A"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">A)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerA']).'</label></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="B" id="question-1-answers-B"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">B)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerB']).'</label></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="C" id="question-1-answers-C"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">C)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerC']).'</label></td></tr>';
    }
echo "</table>";
```

My problem is that the radiobuttons for each question are not independent from another question. For example: If you select first choice C for question 1 and then choice B for question 2, it will remove the choice C from question 1 and basically you can only select one radiobutton for the entire test. How can I fix that?

Thanks

Comment: "and basically you can only select one radiobutton for the entire test" would mean that all the radio buttons should have the same name

Comment: If you want `input` to go in under the same `name` use `name="q1[]"` also, you're echoing `$qcounter` before it's actually set. Before the while loop do `$qcounter = 0;`. You would have known this if you enabled `error_reporting(-1)`

Comment: @Xorifelse yea I have it set above the code I posted, sorry for not including it

Comment: @chris85 yea it works, thanks!

Comment: Okay, I've moved it to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same `name` attribute throughout the loop. Appended something unique there (like your counter) or use an array.

```
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultx)) {
    echo '<tr><td>Question '.$qcounter.'<br/></td></tr>';
    $qcounter++;
    //output rows for radiobuttons
    echo "<tr><td>".($row['Question'])."</td></tr>";
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q' . $qcounter . '" value="A" id="question-1-answers-A"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">A)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerA']).'</label></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q' . $qcounter . '" value="B" id="question-1-answers-B"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">B)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerB']).'</label></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q' . $qcounter . '" value="C" id="question-1-answers-C"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">C)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerC']).'</label></td></tr>';
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixable by either adding the `$qcounter` in the `name` of the radio buttons. Or you can try and get the id(pk) of your question from the DB and add this one to he `name` attribute. This way you already have the id to save the answers/usage to your DB again.

edit: chris85 answered the question while I was typing mine.

Answer (score 0):

You need a different name for the radiobuttons in each question. In that code above, it seems like the names for every question's radio buttons is "q1". Try this:

```
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultx)) {
    echo '<tr><td>Question '.$qcounter.'<br/></td></tr>';
    $qcounter++;
    // Assigning names to radio buttons
    $question_number = "q".$qcounter;

    //output rows for radiobuttons
    echo "<tr><td>".($row['Question'])."</td></tr>";
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="'.$question_number.'" value="A" id="question-1-    answers-A"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">A)&nbsp;'.   ($row['AnswerA']).'</label></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="'.$question_number.'" value="B" id="question-1-answers-B"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">B)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerB']).'</label></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="'.$question_number.'" value="C" id="question-1-answers-C"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">C)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerC']).'</label></td></tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

edit: chris85 posted his comment while I was typing mine. His code is better since it directly appends $qcounter in the buttons themselves, rather than creating an intermediate variable.